# How do I detect power dialog in AccessibilityService

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I am working on a project where we need to alert the user when the power dialog is shown. To display the power dialog (turn off/reboot dialog) we use an `AccessibilityService` together with `performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_POWER_DIALOG)`. This works, however, when this dialog is shown there is no other event thrown even though we put every single eventtype, feedbacktype and flag in the `accessibilityservice.xml`. This is the code we have right now:

AccessibilityService:

```
@Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
        Log.d("TESTING", "EVENT CODE: " + accessibilityEvent.getEventType()); //No event is happening when the power dialog is shown
        switch (accessibilityEvent.getEventType()){
            performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_POWER_DIALOG);
        }
    }
```

accessibilityservice.xml:

```
<accessibility-service
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:packageNames="com.testingaccessibility"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:canRequestEnhancedWebAccessibility="true"
    android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
    android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"/>
```

As you can see I am opening the power dialog with a button click and it is possible to alert the user here, but I can not do that when the user longpresses the power button.

So, is it possible to send an accessibility event when the power dialog opens?

Comment: ,did you find any solution.??

Comment: @AnuragGoel I did not find a way to get an accessibility event when the power dialog opens. However, since the plan was to automatically reboot the phone I slept for a few seconds after calling performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_POWER_DIALOG); and then used getRootInActiveWindow(); to check that the power dialog had loaded. I then did some more checking to make sure it was the right dialog and finally used performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK); on the childs to successfully reboot the phone.

Comment: @FewWords can you let me know how you perform the click event. I am able to capture the power window but all the nodes are coming in as non clickable. If you have some snippet of how you did it will be really helpfull.

Comment: @Ajaynath Well, as I said in the comment above. I used performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK). However, this was 3 years ago and a lot of things have changed so if that is no longer an option I can't help you. I don't have access to that code anymore and I don't remember exactly how I did it, sorry

Comment: @FewWords No issues thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in your accessibility service, change `onAccessibilityEvent` method...

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
    Log.d("TESTING", "EVENT CODE: " + accessibilityEvent.getEventType()); //No event is happening when the power dialog is shown
    if(accessibilityEvent.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("check for power dialog content text")){


       /***do your work***/
    }
}
```